# How to map FK field in MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I save a book, first I map the `BookRequest` fields using MapStruct and then I set the user field of the entity returned from mapper as shown below.

```
public void create(BookRequest request) {
    final Book book = bookRequestMapper.toEntity(request);

    // here I set the User field of the Book 
    book.setUser(userRepository.getReferenceById(request.getUserId()));
    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

However, I am wondering if this is a proper way or can I map the user in the mapper. So, how should I map the user in this scenario? Here is my mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface BookRequestMapper {

    Book toEntity(BookRequest dto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 options:

1: adding custom method

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class BookRequestMapper {

    @Autowired
    protected UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mapping(target = "user", source = "dto.userId", qualifiedByName = "mapUser")
    public abstract Book toEntity(BookRequest dto);

    @Named("mapUser") 
    protected User mapUser(Long userId){
        return userRepository.getReferenceById(userId);
    }

}
```

- Official documentation: [adding-custom-methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)
- Baeldung tutorial: [mapstruct-custom-mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper)

2: usign expression

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class BookRequestMapper {

    @Autowired
    protected UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mapping(target = "user", expression = "java(userRepository.getReferenceById(dto.getUserId()))")
    public abstract Book toEntity(BookRequest dto);

}
```

- Official documentation: [Mapping expression documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)